# Android Studio not recognizing SDKs

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my Android Studio to Beta 0.8.6 but now am not able to build because I cannot seem to get the sdks working correctly. I have checked my path and it is pointing to the correct place and even tried it with different paths. But everytime I try to build I get the same error. I did have to replace my Android Studio to get the beta version but kept my preferences from my previous version.

```
Failed to sync Gradle project 'OlleyVotto'
Error:Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project ':app:libraries:volley'.           Minimum required is 19.1.0
 install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 19.1.0, update version in build file and sync project.
```

I have installed the build tools and followed this direct link but keep getting the same error.

Comment: Did you update the version in your build file?

Comment: Update your build.gradle to point to `buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"`

Answer (score 1):

Update `buildToolsVersion` in `build.gradle`, like

```
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
```

And you may need to update your build tools in SDK Manager.

Comment: you can find it under: project-name/module-name/build.gradle